# How does the event handler use the variables from the loop?

Tags: javascript, scope

In my code, I create buttons that use the variable `i` in the loop declared via `var` keyword. Now each button will log 10, i.e. the last value of the variable. The question is, where does the variable in the handler come from? Does he pick it up from the main scope? And in the case of `let`, 9 scopes are created and the handler, when clicked, accesses i from each of them? I always thought that the handler remembers `i` at each step of the loop

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <script>
            const start = () => {
                const body = document.querySelector('body');
 
                for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                  const button = document.createElement('button');
                  button.onclick = function() {
                    console.log(i);
                  }
                  console.log(i)
                  body.appendChild(button);
                }
            }
            start();
        </script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript variables are reference typed. So in the for loop scope there is only one `i`. And it is increased at every iterative. Thats why every button prints the last value.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is due to scoping and closures. variable defined with var is function scoped and since onClick is a function, closures comes into play and at the end of loop, value to closure is 10.

variables defined with let is block scoped and hence a new scope is created for each loop with value 1.

Comment: So,
1)event handlers are created after the loop has passed?
2)or access variables from the scopes created during the loop?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is classical js problem caused by function scope of 'var'. It is solved since ES6 via 'let' and 'const' because they have block scope (every {} creates scope for variables created via 'let' and 'const'). If you change iterator declaration from 'var' to 'let' it will works as expected.